# Проблема не совместимости версий , почему?

Tags: php, phpunit

После запуска PHP unit теста , я получаю данную ошибку .. 
Из прочитанного в сети говорят что данная ошибка из за несовместимости версий , но не пойму где у меня несовместимость версий ?

PHP Version (php -v  PHP 7.1.7) 
PHPUNIT versions : * 7.0.3

Ошибка ;

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?
```

Код который мешает запуску теса ; Это код библиотеки .

```
 /**
 * @throws SebastianBergmann\RecursionContext\InvalidArgumentException
 */
 public function getName(bool $withDataSet = true): ?string
 {
    if ($withDataSet) {
        return $this->name . $this->getDataSetAsString(false);
    }

    return $this->name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Данная запись

```
public function getName(bool $withDataSet = true): ?string
```

говорит, что метод вернет тип string **или null**. Это `или null` определяется наличием символа `?` перед именем типа.

Функционал декларирования возвращаемого значения появился в PHP 7.0, а функционал декларирования `или null` - в PHP 7.1

Т.к. PHPUnit у Вас для версии 7.0, то о функционале `или null` он ничего не знает и запись `?string` считает ошибкой

Comment: Какую версию PHP Unit мне надо для корректной работы ? 
Моя версия PHP 7.1.17 как написано выше ..

Comment: @Mekudad Согласно этой [ссылке](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php) новее 1 декабря 2016 года

Comment: Ваще не понял зачем ссылку эту дали ??????

Comment: @Mekudad Там написано какие версии PHP поддерживает та или иная версия PHPUnit

Comment: Вы сомной загадками говорите чтоли ? Вот доки https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html , что из написанного я делаю нетак ?

Comment: @Mekudad Я понятия не имею, что вы делаете. Как я могу сказать, что вы делаете не так? Вы даже версию PHPUnit не озвучили

Comment: Вам стоит читать по внимательнее с верху в вопросе всё написанно